# Using github and gitbash with multiple users & ssh identities

Tags: git, github, ssh

I would like to consult the community on how should I set up my terminal for it to automatically use the correct identity file when pushing to a repro.

Currently, what I am trying is making use of ssh config files:

~/ssh/config

```
# First account
Host github.com:my_first_github_account
   HostName github.com
   User git
   IdentityFile ~/.ssh/id_ed25519_user1
   
# Second account
Host github.com:my_second_github_account  
   HostName github.com
   User git
   IdentityFile ~/.ssh/id_ed25519_user2
```

I map whichever git user-specific endpoint to its identity file, and it so works when authorizing myself on it:

```
> ssh git@github.com:my_first_github_account
Hi my_first_github_account! You've successfully authenticated, but GitHub does not provide shell access.
Connection to github.com closed.

> ssh git@github.com:my_second_github_account
Hi my_second_github_account! You've successfully authenticated, but GitHub does not provide shell access.
Connection to github.com closed.
```

and my current issue is that when pushing with `git` to a remote origin (which is of course authorized to do so) it uses the wrong identity file, not the one that should of been considered:

```
> git config --get remote.origin.url
git@github.com:my_first_github_account/my-repo.git
> git push
ERROR: Repository not found.
fatal: Could not read from remote repository.

Please make sure you have the correct access rights
and the repository exists.
```

Comment: Don't try to use a colon in a host name, because ssh / scp syntax (which then bleeds into Git syntax in Git's extended URL format) uses colons for its own purposes.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `:account_name` part should not be part of the `Host` name in your `.ssh/config`.

Apparently, command line ssh is ok with having a hostname which contains `:` (I didn't know that), but `git` extracts the `github.com` part and runs an ssh command which tries `ssh github.com` -- and your `.ssh/config` does not contain any config for `github.com` alone.

---

The fix is simple :

change your `Host` values, e.g to `Host github.work` and `Host github.perso`, and use :

```
git clone github.work:username/repo
git clone github.perso:username/repo
```

---

*for the sake of completeness* : you *could* work with the hostnames you defined, just use the longer url syntax to target your github repo :

```
git clone ssh://github.com:username/username/repo.git
```

but it's way more convenient to choose a host name which works with the short url form.